# Como mostrar consulta de 2 tablas en un datagrid donde las tablas y columnas estan cargadas en 2 combobox C# o VB en cualquier lenguaje

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, visual-basic

soy nuevo en el mundo de programacion.
Para ser mas especifico, estoy realizando una aplicación en visual studio 2022 con C#, .NET6.0. en un combobox cargo la base de datos con la que trabajare, hago conexión a toda la data que contiene. Las tablas de mi base de datos la estoy cargando en un combobox1 donde cargo las tablas por sus nombres, y en el combobox2 cargo las columnas por encabezado de la tabla que escogí en el combobox1.

Es una aplicación dinámica.no ingreso hago ningún tipo de entrada de datos, solo cargo los comboboxes.

[image: pantalla del modulo]

****Objetivo****
quiero que en un botón al dar click haga una union de las 2 tablas y las cargue al datagrid

/*intento mas cercano sin generar error pero solo usando una tabla */

```
    private void BtnCruce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HNBND100421005;Initial Catalog='" + cmbBD.Text + "';Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        Da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +cmbtabla1.Text, con);
        Dt = new DataTable();
        MessageBox.Show("Mostrando Datos de Cruce");
        Da.Fill(Dt);
        dtvgvista.DataSource = Dt;
        con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
private void BtnCruce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HNBND100421005;Initial Catalog='" + cmbBD.Text + "';Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        Da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +cmbtabla1.Text + " UNION SELECT * FROM " + cmbtabla2.Text, con);
        Dt = new DataTable();
        MessageBox.Show("Mostrando Datos de Cruce");
        Da.Fill(Dt);
        dtvgvista.DataSource = Dt;
        con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudo con exito :), la quise puntuar con flecha arriba pero no me permitio